# Saving a JComboBox Selection to an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, selection, jcombobox

I cannot retrieve the selection in the JComboBox that was selected by the user. the J ComboBox inclued a list of car registration numbers, which then the user has to select one and it will be added to the booking ArrayList. Unfortunately it is not working properly. and the booking  is not being saved because of this. Please Help Me! Maybe I need to change the get Method for the combo box.

```
ArrayList BookingList = CarRentalSystem.BookingList;
ArrayList CarList = CarRentalSystem.CarList;
UsingFiles BookingFile = CarRentalSystem.BookingFile;
String [] regNums;

public NewBooking() {

        regNums = new String[CarList.size()+1];
        for (int i = 0; i< CarList.size();i++){
            regNums[i] = ""+((Car)CarList.get(i)).getCarNum();
        }
                initComponents();

....
Booking book = new Booking();

String regNum = cmbCar.getActionCommand();
 book.getRegNum();
```

Comment: And that code is related with what? Learn how to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "you can't"? What does this code do? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it exhibit some strange behavior? Something else? Where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: yes it runs. this is a car rental system. the user saves new cars in the arrayList CarList. this includes the registration number which i then displayed in the combobox. but when the user chooses the field from the combo box, it isn't stored in the booking arraylist.

Comment: Where is your listener for your combo box? If you're having a problem with selection, then you _must_ show your listener code, because that's where the selection comes from. If you don't know what a listener is see [**Writing Event Listeners**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

Comment: Comment from @onoitsjon - _"Do you have a Listener on the JComboBox or Button (attached with an action) that calls JComboBox.getSelectedItem() or JComboBox.getSelectedIndex() ?"_

Comment: I have a JFrame, GUI Swing thing, this is just the coding in it.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to understand what u want can you add more code?

try this to convert your list into a String Array that u pass in as a argument to your combobox.

```
    public String[] regNums() {

        String tArray[] = null;

        for (int i=0; i<carList.size(); i++){           
            //Convert into a String[] and put the arrayList values in it.
            tArray = carList.toArray(new String[i]);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already converted it to string. I just need to get the method instead of getActionCommand() correct in order to retrieve the information